# FormattedTextField based on user's input

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I am trying to create a FormattedTextField where the user informs the price of the product. But I don't know how to format the field since the product can have any size (e.g. $1, 72$, or $489). I'd like the field could have this format: "xxx.00" the x's are numbers, but they can be one or more depending on the price of product.

How to create the required format?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: To build a program so I can manage the costs of my shop.

Comment: Just use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)):`NumberFormat format =NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);format.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(format);field.setValue(0.0);`

Comment: Why not use a table?

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans using the Swing GUI Builder you can accomplish this by right-clicking on your FormattedTextField and going to **Properties**.  Then select **formatterFactory** under Properties, and select the **currency** category.  Then select the third option which looks like this:

```
¤#,##0.00
```

That will give you exactly what you're looking you, and it will format the number how you want once the user clicks out of the textfield.

To accomplish this in code it will be this:

```
jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(new java.text.DecimalFormat("¤#,##0.00"))));
```